# Combine multiple nebensatz in one long sentence?

Tags: english-to-german, verb, subordinate-clause

I'm learning German myself, so I cannot ask anyone else, except this portal, please tell me which sentence is correct in terms of grammar (or if both are not correct, then please add your sentence).

1. Als ich ein Kind war, hat mein Vater mir viele Märchen bevor ich ins Bett geht erzählt
2. Als ich ein Kind war, hat mein Vater mir viele Märchen erzählt, bevor ich ins Bett geht

English sentence:

When I was a child, my father told me many fairy tales before I go to bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are from the Nebensatz point of view pretty right (just that it's "gegangen bin" ("geht" is Präsens):

1. Als ich ein Kind war, hat mein Vater mir viele Märchen, bevor ich ins Bett gegangen bin, erzählt.
2. Als ich ein Kind war, hat mein Vater mir viele Märchen erzählt, bevor ich ins Bett gegangen bin.

The second one is more readable. Mind the commas, though, they add significantly to the reading (and are required by grammar rules at least for the first sentence).

Comment: Thanks, I think the second sentence is nicer, haha.

Comment: *Geht* is also third person and therefore mismatches *I* (first person).

Comment: @guidot thanks :)), that is minor error, haha